# How to resize the container's height of listviewitem of Telerik UI for UWP

Tags: c#, telerik, uwp, radlistview

It's the first time I use Telerik UI for UWP.
And I add the listview to xaml:

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="rlvProducts" Grid.Row="1" IsCheckModeActive="True" FontSize="12">
<telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I get the listview like this:
[image]

You can see that the item height is too much.

I tried to reset the font size, the height of the textblock of the template, but it didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to resize the height of listviewitem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a custom `RadListViewItem` style, like this:

```
<data:RadListView>
    <data:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
    <data:RadListView.ItemStyle>
        <Style TargetType="listView:RadListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </data:RadListView.ItemStyle>
</data:RadListView>
```

You can of course further tweak the `Style` to meet your needs.

For more information on ItemStyling, including ItemSwipe styling, [see this article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radlistview/features/listview-styling).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<fieldset>` tag within item template to control it, e.g :

```
 <telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="rlvProducts" Grid.Row="1" IsCheckModeActive="True" FontSize="12">
  <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
    <fieldset  style="float: left; width: 350px; height: 150px;/>
    <DataTemplate >... </DataTemplate>
  </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```

See here for more details: [doc](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/listview/templates/data-and-layout)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it when I'm back to work.

Comment: I checked the code and the doc but it didn't work for me. And the doc is for RadListView for ASP.NET AJAX not for UWP.